# C# - Linq MultiThreading with varying Max/Min Threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, semaphore

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 8000;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;

List<Match> Combos = new Regex("^(.{5,}):(.{6,})$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileNames[0])).OfType<Match>().ToList();
var query = Combos.ToObservable().SelectMany(s => Observable.Start(() => new
{
    grab = checkall(s.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""), s.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""))
})).ObserveOn(this).Do(x =>
{
    try
    {
        TotalChecked.Text = "Tested: " + (int.Parse(TotalChecked.Text.Substring(7)) + 1).ToString();
        progressBar2.Value = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * int.Parse(TotalChecked.Text.Substring(7))) / Combos.Count);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        TotalChecked.Text = "Tested: " + (int.Parse(TotalChecked.Text.Substring(7)) + 1).ToString();
        progressBar2.Value = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * int.Parse(TotalChecked.Text.Substring(7))) / Combos.Count);
    }
});
query.ToArray().ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(x =>
{
    CheckButton.Location = new Point(CheckButton.Location.X + 31, 9);
    CheckButton.Width -= 31;
});
```

The code above uses regex on a text file and then executes a function.
It works just fine, but now I want it to execute multiple DIFFERENT functions and only allow a set amount of threads on some of them.

For example:

```
var query = Combos.ToObservable().SelectMany(s => Observable.Start(() => new
{
    grab = checkall(s.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""), s.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")),
    //This one should be LIMITED to only 5 threads MAX!
    grab2 = checktwo(Hi, Hello)
}))
```

In the code above I added `grab2` which should have a maximum of 5 threads allocate to it.

To be honest I have no idea how I could execute a method like this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve and maybe remove any code that isn't relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to some code gets executed only by `n` threads, you need a [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a.aspx), in this case [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) is enough

```
// 5 threads to run in parallel, all 5 can start immidiately
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);

// ...

try
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    //This one should be LIMITED to only 5 threads MAX!
    grab2 = checktwo(Hi, Hello);
}
finally
{
    // ensure the release of semaphore
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

You can even wait for it in [`async` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805.aspx):

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
```

Comment: Never heard of a semaphore. This is actually a really nice read. Ill try it out now and let you know the results.

Comment: Im so sorry, I forgot my Email and Password. You have now been marked as answer, this worked TREMENDOUSLY!

Comment: P.S: I did have to slightly modify how your code ran, mostly the top, it says `(5)` but thats the initial thread count, not the maximum, so to solve it I simply used its MaxCount parameter by simply doing `(5,5)`

Comment: Also instead of putting it in a Try-Finally I put it directly inside checktwo before the actual code starts. I couldnt use .WaitAsync() as it ultimately does nothing. But right before return true; doing a .Release() works splendid :)

Comment: @user7842865 I used the `try/finally` as, if you got the exception, the semaphore wouldn't released, which is really bad for your system

Comment: yes but how my actual function returns data I had to put it before the return and not in a try finally.

Comment: You can put the semaphore calss **inside** the functions, the effect still will be the same, and you can create a dedicated semaphore for each of them

Comment: thats what im doing atm, for each of them I dedicate them a SemaphoreSlim, and for the Linq ThreadPool I give it 150 threads so that all of them can run.

Comment: You still should use `try/finally` to guarantee the semaphore release